# How to change markdown blocks family-font in jupyter lab?

Tags: markdown, jupyter-lab

I have jupyter lab 3.2.1 version. I want to use Consolas font for rendering in markdown blocks in .ipynb files.

If I go to advaced settings and change family-font preferece in the section Markdown it works only to .md files (only markdown files and not to notebooks)

[Settings changed only for .md files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZEfc.png)

If I go to Notebook section and change "markdownCellConfig" to set "fotfamily" it changes the font used to edit Markdown blocks, but not the font used to render.

[Settings changed for font used to write Markdown but rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jje5Q.jpg)

[How it look those last changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr643.png)

I tried a lot to change Theme configuration:

[Theme changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSaIF.png)

But I could not find the right key-value to override theme config, and its very hard to read the documentation.
Any Idea?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)